# limsup and liminf of sequence of random variables and Borel Cantelli

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

For a sequence of independent random variables $X_n$, if we have $P( \limsup [X_n > a] ) = 1$, then $P( [ \limsup X_n ] > a ) = 1$. Does this automatically mean $P( \liminf [X_n > a] ) = 1$ as well?

Since $P(([\limsup X_n] > a)^c)=P( \liminf(X_n > a)^c)=P([\liminf X_n]\le a) = 0$, we have $P( \liminf [X_n > a] ) = 1$.

Please let me know if I have made stupid mistakes. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $P(\liminf\{X_n>a\}^c)=P(\liminf\{X_n\le a\})\ne P(\liminf X_n\le a)$. Actually $P(\liminf\{X_n\le a\})=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\cap_{k\ge n}\{X_k\le a\})$, i.e. probability that *all* $X_k\le a$ in the tail, not just *sometimes* as $\liminf X_n\le a$ tells us.

Comment: If we have $P(liminf \{X_n \le a\})=1$, does that imply liminf $X_n \le a$ then? Since all $X_k \le$ are in the tail with probability 1. But we can't conclude anything if $P(liminf \{X_n \le a\})=0$.

Comment: Also, does $P(X_n>a i. o.)= P(limsup(X_n>a))$? I think it does, since $X_n>a$ is an event.

Comment: Could be you were mixing up $\liminf$ for *functions* and for *events*? P.S. The last equality is correct.

Comment: I want to show the sequence of random variables $X_n$ has liminf$X_n$ =a. But I only know the probability of events such as {$X_n$>a} or {$X_n$<a}, and Borel Cantelli's lemma. So I wonder how to conclude anything about liminf$X_n$ as a random variable, from the probability of liminf of events

Comment: Related to my question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522359/what-is-the-difference-b-w-colorred-limsup-w-k-k-colorred-le-1 @A.G.

Comment: Rann, edited answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important inequalities

Williams - Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

Deduced similarly:

(iii) If $\liminf x_n > z$, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n > z)$ eventually (that is, for infinitely many n)

(iv) If $\liminf x_n < z $, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n < z)$ infinitely often (that is, for infinitely many n)

---

> $$P( \limsup [X_n > a] ) = 1 \to P( [ \limsup X_n ] > a) = 1$$

No. Consider $X_n = a + \frac{1}{n}$.

The converse, which is,

$$P( \limsup [X_n > a] ) = 1 \leftarrow P( [ \limsup X_n ] > a) = 1$$

is true (see above).

---

> $$P( [ \limsup X_n ] > a) = 1 \to P( \liminf [X_n > a] ) = 1$$

No.

$$P( [ \limsup X_n ] > a) = 1 \to P( \limsup (X_n  > a)) = 1$$

$$P( \limsup (X_n  > a)) = 1 \nrightarrow P( \liminf [X_n > a] ) = 1$$

The converse of the latter, which is,

$$P( \liminf [X_n > a] ) = 1 \to P( \limsup (X_n  > a)) = 1$$

is true (obviously?).

---

> $$P(([\limsup X_n] > a)^c)=P( \liminf(X_n > a)^c)$$

No.

$$P(([\limsup X_n] > a)^c) = P([\limsup X_n] \le a)$$

$$P( \liminf[(X_n > a)^c]) = P( \liminf(X_n \le a))$$

$$P( [\liminf(X_n > a)]^c) = P( \limsup(X_n \le a))$$

---

> $$P( \liminf(X_n > a)^c)=P([\liminf X_n]\le a)$$

No.

$$P( \liminf[(X_n > a)^c]) = P( \liminf(X_n \le a))$$

$$P( [\liminf(X_n > a)]^c) = P( \limsup(X_n \le a))$$

$$P([\liminf X_n]\le a) = P(([\liminf X_n] > a)^C)$$

---

> $$P([\liminf X_n]\le a) = 0 \to P( \liminf [X_n > a] ) = 1$$

Yes. Contrapositive of 3