# Is it correct to say that ($\color{red}{(} \limsup |W_k|/k\color{red}{)} \le 1) \supseteq \limsup \color{red}{(}|W_k|/k \le 1\color{red}{)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Let $W_0, W_1, W_2, \dots$ be random variables on a probability space
>   $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ where
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(|W_k|>k) <\infty$$
>
> Prove that $$\limsup \frac{|W_k|}{k} \le 1 \ \text{a.s.} $$

---

I initially thought the conclusion meant $(**)$ when it really means $(*)$:

$$P(\color{red}{(} \limsup |W_k|/k\color{red}{)} \le 1) = 1 \ \text{(*)}$$

$$P(\limsup \color{red}{(}|W_k|/k \le 1\color{red}{)}) = 1 \ \text{(**)}$$

---

What I tried:

By the first Borel-Cantelli Lemma, we have $P(\limsup (|W_k| > k)) = 0$

$\to P(\limsup (|W_k|/k > 1)) = 0$

$\to P(\liminf (|W_k|/k > 1)) = 0$

$\to P([\liminf (|W_k|/k > 1)]^C) = 1$

$\to P(\limsup \color{red}{(}|W_k|/k \le 1\color{red}{)}) = 1$

$\to P(\color{red}{(} \limsup |W_k|/k\color{red}{)} \le 1) = 1$ QED assuming $(**)$ implies $(*)$.

---

Is it really the case that $(**)$ implies $(*)$? Here is why I think such:

$\forall \omega \in \Omega, \omega \in (\limsup \color{red}{(}|W_k|/k \le 1\color{red}{)})$

Then $\forall m \ge 1, \exists n \ge m$ s.t.

$\omega \in (\frac{|W_n(\omega)|}{n} \le 1)$

[$\to \omega \in (\limsup \frac{|W_n(\omega)|}{n} \le \limsup 1 = 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353642/x-n-leq-y-n-implies-liminf-x-n-leq-liminf-y-n-and-limsup-x-n-leq-lims?lq=1)

Now if $(\color{red}{(} \limsup |W_k|/k\color{red}{)} \le 1) \supseteq \limsup \color{red}{(}|W_k|/k \le 1\color{red}{)}$, then it follows by monotonicity that

$(**)$ implies $(*)$ QED.

---

However $(*)$ does not imply $(**)$ because it does not hold that $(\color{red}{(} \limsup |W_k|/k\color{red}{)} \le 1) \subseteq \limsup \color{red}{(}|W_k|/k \le 1\color{red}{)}$. Counterexample given in comments below. I guess the intuitive explanation is that

$\limsup \frac{|W_n(\omega)|}{n} \le \limsup 1$

--/--> $\frac{|W_n(\omega)|}{n} \le 1$

for similar reasons that

$x_n \le y_n \to \lim x_n \le \lim y_n$, [if those limits exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353642/x-n-leq-y-n-implies-liminf-x-n-leq-liminf-y-n-and-limsup-x-n-leq-lims) (1)

but

$\lim x_n \le \lim y_n$ --/--> $x_n \le y_n$ (2), which makes sense:

(1) has an infinite number of statements which imply 3 statements (limsup, liminf, limsup=liminf)

(2) has 3 statements that claims to imply an infinite number of statements

Is that right?

---

Edit based on what Daniel Fischer said:

To prove $$\liminf \{\frac{W_k(\omega)}{k} \le 1\} \subseteq \{\limsup \frac{W_k(\omega)}{k} \le 1\}:$$

Suppose $$\omega \in \liminf \{\frac{W_k(\omega)}{k} \le 1\}$$

Then $\exists m \ge 1$ s.t. $\forall k \ge m$,

$$\omega \in \{\frac{|W_k(\omega)|}{k} \le 1\}$$

[Since $\frac{|W_k(\omega)|}{k} \le 1 \to \limsup \frac{|W_k(\omega)|}{k} \le \limsup 1 = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353642/x-n-leq-y-n-implies-liminf-x-n-leq-liminf-y-n-and-limsup-x-n-leq-lims?lq=1), we have

$$\to \omega \in \{\limsup \frac{|W_k(\omega)|}{k} \le 1\}$$

Comment: What does $\limsup$ of a numerical sequence mean ?
$$\inf_N\left(\sup_{n\geq N}a_n\right)=\limsup a_n \leq1 \Longleftrightarrow \forall k\; \exists N\;\::\:\sup_{n\geq N} a_n\leq1-1/k $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \forall k\; \exists N\;\forall n\geq N\::\: a_n\leq1-1/k$$

Comment: FIRST OF ALL,  "$a.s$" doesn't mean anything in the convergence of that series !

Comment: $(**)$ implies $(*)$ but not the reverse. Counter-example: $W_k/k$ is constant and converging to $1$ from above. Then $(*)$ holds but $(**)$ does not.

Comment: @FardadPouran No, this is not a characterization of $\limsup a_n\leqslant1$ (consider $a_n=1+1/n$, say).

Comment: Thanks for your notice. I was wrong.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks! How do you know $(**)$ implies $(*)$?

Comment: @A.S. What do you mean by constant and converging to 1 from above? $W_k/k = 1$ if it is constant and converges to 1 right?

Comment: @BCLC For example $W_k/k=1+1/k$.

Comment: @A.S. Oh constant in terms of $\omega$. Thanks. I'll try it out later

Comment: @A.S. it's gonna be complicated ! $a.s$ is different from A.S. !!

Comment: @Did Dr. MV, kjetil b halvorsen, Cameron Williams, avid19, I edited my question

Comment: "I initially thought the conclusion meant (∗) when it really means (∗∗)" The conclusion definitely means (∗), **obviously**. For the nth time I suggest to stop asking questions which puts you completely out of your depth (which is basically also the advice you received on meta). But you know better, yes? So you will continue to try to take advantage of the vulnerabilities of the mse system, I guess.

Comment: Are my eyes bad or the inequality looks exactly the same to me?

Comment: @Nameless I used colours?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try to get things straight. We have two conditions,

\begin{align}
P\left(\left\{\omega \in \Omega : \limsup_{k\to\infty} \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \leqslant 1\right\}\right) &= 1,\text{ and} \tag{$\ast$}\\
P\left(\limsup_{k\to\infty} \left\{\omega\in \Omega : \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \leqslant 1 \right\}\right) &= 1. \tag{$\ast\ast$}
\end{align}

The question is whether one condition implies the other. An inclusion between the sets $A := \left\{\omega \in \Omega : \limsup_{k\to\infty} \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \leqslant 1\right\}$ and $B := \limsup_{k\to\infty} \left\{\omega\in \Omega : \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \leqslant 1 \right\}$ would give us such an implication.

However, in general we have neither $A \subset B$ nor $B \subset A$. We can use the verbal description of the limes superior of sets to describe $B$ as

$$B = \left\{\omega \in \Omega : \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \leqslant 1 \text{ for infinitely many } k \right\}.$$

This implies $\liminf\limits_{k\to \infty} \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \leqslant 1$ for all $\omega \in B$, but it doesn't say anything about $\limsup\limits_{k\to \infty} \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k}$. We could for example have $W_k \equiv 0$ for odd $k$, and $W_k \equiv 5k$ for even $k$. Then we have $B = \Omega$ and $A = \varnothing$, since for this example $\limsup\limits_{k\to \infty} \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} = 5$ for all $\omega$.

On the other hand, we could have $W_k \equiv k(1+2^{-k})$ for all $k$, then we have $A = \Omega$ and $B = \varnothing$, since $\frac{\lvert w_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \to 1$ uniformly on $\Omega$, but $\frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} = 1 + 2^{-k} > 1$ for all $k$ and $\omega$.

Thus, we have no implication whatsoever between the conditions $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$.

But the Borel-Cantelli lemma yields something stronger than $(\ast\ast)$. Namely, from

$$\sum_k P(\{\omega\in \Omega : \lvert W_k(\omega) \rvert > k\}) < +\infty$$

we conclude that the set of $\omega$ such that $\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert > k$ for infinitely many $k$ is a null set. In other words, for almost all $\omega$, we have $\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert \leqslant k$ for all but finitely many $k$. In other words, from the Borel-Cantelli lemma we obtain

$$P\left(\liminf_{k \to \infty}\left\{\omega \in \Omega : \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \leqslant 1\right\}\right) = 1.\tag{$\ast{\ast}\ast$}$$

And now, we note that

$$C = \liminf_{k\to \infty} \left\{\omega \in \Omega : \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \leqslant 1 \right\} = \left\{\omega \in \Omega : \frac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \leqslant 1 \text{ for all but finitely many } k\right\}$$

is clearly a subset of $A$. Hence we have the implication $(\ast{\ast}\ast) \implies (\ast)$. Also it's clear that $C \subset B$, whence we have the implication $(\ast{\ast}\ast) \implies (\ast\ast)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the brilliant elaborate answer, Daniel Fischer. I can still remember your comments on my real analysis questions last year before you became a mod, iirc. Guess A.S. was wrong

Comment: Actually Daniel Fischer, I get how $(***)$ implies $(**)$ but how does $(***)$ imply $(*)$?

Comment: $(\ast{\ast}\ast)$ says that for almost all $\omega\in \Omega$ there are only finitely many $k$ with $\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert > k$. So for almost all $\omega$ we have $\dfrac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \in [0,1]$ for all but finitely many $k$. For these $\omega$, we clearly have $\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty} \dfrac{\lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert}{k} \in [0,1]$.

Comment: How is my edit in the last part? Why $\ge 0$? Thanks Daniel Fischer! ^-^

Comment: It's $\geqslant 0$ because we have an absolute value. In your edit, you're abusing notation, so strictly it doesn't make sense. When translated into proper notation, it's correct, however. Even when abusing notation, I would strongly recommend to use curly braces to denote sets. $\liminf \left\{ \lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert/k \leqslant 1\right\} \subset \left\{ \limsup \lvert W_k(\omega)\rvert/k \leqslant 1\right\}$ is easier to interpret.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks hahaha. How about now?

Comment: You have a misplaced brace, $\{ \limsup \dotsc\} \le 1$ doesn't make sense, must be $\{ \limsup \dotsc \le 1\}$.

Comment: Oh because curly brackets denote sets i.e. events? Okay fixed. Anything else? ^-^

Comment: Well, the "$\forall \omega \in \Omega$" doesn't belong there. As written, you'd claim that $\liminf \{\dotsc\} = \Omega$, but what you actually want to say is that for all $\omega\in \Omega$ we have the implication $\omega \in \liminf \{\dotsc\} \implies \omega \in \{\limsup \dotsc \leqslant 1\}$. You could completely drop the "$\forall \omega \in \Omega$" or move it into an introductory sentence (For all $\omega\in\Omega$ we have …).

Comment: Thanks very much Daniel Fischer. Anything else? ^-^

Comment: Nah, it's okay now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the brilliant elaborate answer + comments, Daniel Fischer. I can still remember your comments on my real analysis questions last year before you became a mod, iirc. Guess A.S. was wrong

Comment: Daniel Fischer does $(***) \to (*)$ require [iid](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537905/proof-convergence-of-random-variables-almost-sure/1538627#comment3144808_1538503)? That seems to be what Did is suggesting

Comment: No, we don't need iid. And I don't see an indication of Did suggesting that in the other thread.

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between this situation and the other one? The strict inequality?

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing what you're writing over there. I would recommend a) using words in addition to formulae, and b) avoiding short-cut notation. Dropping the "$\omega \in \Omega$" from the sets isn't too bad, but one should always retain the set braces "$\{\dotsc\}$", confusing $\limsup \{ f_n \leqslant c\}$ and $\{\limsup f_n \leqslant c\}$ or similar things is deadly.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll edit

Comment: However, for what apparently is called the second Borel-Cantelli lemma (not being a probabilist, I had to look up what that is), one needs independence (but not identical distribution).

Comment: Daniel Fischer, I think I already got it. Thanks anyway ^-^

Answer (score -2):

The difference between the two formulas in the title is that the first one makes sense and the second one is meaningless.  The second one pretends to form the lim sup of some statements (not of numbers), and there's no such thing.

Comment: This is incorrect. The second formula is $\limsup$ of a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$ which is well-defined.

Comment: @A.S. I assume you're identifying the formula $|W_k|/k\leq 1$ with the set $\{x\in\Omega:|W_k(x)|/k\leq1\}$. If so, then I agree; the lim sup of a sequence of sets does make sense.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Delete answer?

Comment: @BCLC No. Although reading a formula $\phi$ as a set $S$ makes sense of the title, it destroys the sense of the second displayed formula in the question, which would then read "$S$ almost surely".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Um, what?

Comment: @BCLC "Lim sup" applies to numbers and to sets, not to statements.  "A.s." applies to statements, not to numbers or sets. Applying both to the same expression (as in the title and in the second displayed formula) requires giving that expression two different meanings.

Comment: Andreas Blass, so there IS meaning? 'the second one is meaningless' ?

Comment: @BCLC The second part of the title is meaningless as it stands. It acquires a meaning if you change your understanding of the formula so that it denotes a set instead of a formula. When you make that change, the second displayed formula in the question loses its meaning. It can regain its meaning if you change your understanding of the formula back to the normal one, a formula rather than a set, but then the second half of the title loses its meaning. If you switch back and forth fast enough, you can probably create a blur in which everything looks meaningful, but I'd rather avoid blurs.

Comment: Errrrrrrrrrrrrrrr what? What do you mean by formula? limsup(events) is an event right?

Comment: @BCLC As I said, lim sup makes sense for sets, so indeed lim sup of events is an event. What I mean by formula in this discussion is the inequality $|W_k|/k\leq1$, which you have, as I wrote before, reinterpreted as a set (an event), namely the set $\{x\in\Omega:|W_k(x)|/k\leq 1\}$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass But the set you gave is abbreviated by omitting x and $\Omega$ right?

Comment: @BCLC It seems to be so abbreviated by you.

Comment: I should clarify the status of such abbreviations. In some contexts, notably in the argument of a probability function, this abbreviation is quite commonly used.  In others, it is uncommon and, in my opinion, likely to cause confusion.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for the info. I'll try to be clear when I ask non-probabilistic real analysis or measure theory questions I guess