# Proof convergence of random variables (almost sure)

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $\left\{ X_{n}\right\} _{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables. Prove that $X_{n}\overset{a.e.}{\rightarrow}0$ if and only if, for all $\epsilon>0$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\textrm{P}\left(\left|X_{n}\right|>\epsilon\right)<\infty$.

I guess I have to use the Borel Cantelli Lemma, right? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah,Borel Cantelli is a good idea. So....?

Comment: But I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Well, suppose that $\sum_n P(|X_n|>\epsilon)<\infty$ for all $\epsilon>0$. What do you get if you apply the Borel Cantelli lemma?

Comment: The probability that infinitely many of them occur is 0, i.e.,  $\textrm{P}\left(\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\limsup}\left|X_{n}\right|\right)=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by $P(\limsup_n |X_n|)$?

Comment: Edited answer. Sorry Jyrki Lahtonen♦  Also, thanks @Did :P

Comment: @Jyrki 1. Do you condone the continual deleting/reposting copies of answers we are witnessing here and elsewhere? I thought this was against the rules of the site, is this not? 2. The answer below by the offending OP is (again) false. The time the detection of the crap requires is increasing because the answers are longer and longer and because the OP modifies them repeatedly. 3. IMHO, you (the mods) should have stopped the circus this OP is causing, already long ago. Are we witnessing the kind of degeneration of a situation we already observed with some other users?

Comment: Edited answer...

Answer (score -1):

Important inequalities

Williams - Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

Deduced similarly:

(iii) If $\liminf x_n > z$, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n > z)$ eventually (that is, for infinitely many n)

(iv) If $\liminf x_n < z $, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n < z)$ infinitely often (that is, for infinitely many n)

---

'if'

Suppose $\forall \epsilon>0$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\textrm{P}\left(\left|X_{n}\right|>\epsilon\right)<\infty$$

By BCL1, we have

$$\textrm{P}\left(\limsup [\left|X_{n}\right|>\epsilon\right]) = 0$$

$$\to \textrm{P}\left(\liminf [\left|X_{n}\right|\le\epsilon\right]) = 1$$

$$\to \textrm{P}\left([\liminf \left|X_{n}\right|]\le\epsilon\right) = 1 \ \text{and} \ \textrm{P}\left([\limsup \left|X_{n}\right|]\le\epsilon\right) = 1$$

$$\to \textrm{P}\left([\liminf \left|X_{n}\right|]=0\right) = 1 \ \text{and} \ \textrm{P}\left([\limsup \left|X_{n}\right|]=0\right) = 1$$

$$\to \textrm{P}\left([\lim \left|X_{n}\right|]=0\right) = 1$$

$$\to \textrm{P}\left([\left|\lim  X_{n}\right|]=0\right) = 1$$

$$\to \textrm{P}\left([\lim X_{n}]=0\right) = 1$$

---

'only if'

Suppose $\exists \epsilon_0 > 0$ s.t.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\textrm{P}\left(\left|X_{n}\right|>\epsilon_0\right)=\infty$$

By BCL2, we have

$$\textrm{P}\left(\limsup [\left|X_{n}\right|>\epsilon_0\right]) = 1$$

$$\to \textrm{P}\left([\limsup \left|X_{n}\right|]>\epsilon_0\right) = 1$$

$$\to \textrm{P}\left([\limsup \left|X_{n}\right|]\le\epsilon_0\right) = 0$$

$$\to \textrm{P}\left(\liminf \left[|X_{n}\right|\le\epsilon_0]\right) = 0$$

However since

$$\textrm{P}\left([\lim X_{n}]=0\right) = 1,$$

we have

$$\textrm{P}\left([\limsup \left|X_{n}\right|]=0\right) = 1$$

$$\to \forall \epsilon > 0, \textrm{P}\left([\limsup \left|X_{n}\right|]<\epsilon\right) = 1$$

$$\to \forall \epsilon > 0, \textrm{P}\left(\liminf \left[|X_{n}\right|< \epsilon]\right) = 1$$

Choose $\epsilon = \epsilon_0$ to get:

$$\textrm{P}\left(\liminf \left|[X_{n}\right|< \epsilon_0]\right) = 1 ↯$$

$\therefore, \forall \epsilon>0, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\textrm{P}\left(\left|X_{n}\right|>\epsilon\right)<\infty$ QED

Comment: @TripleX If you know the Borel cantelli lemma, this problem is really not difficult. So please try to solve it on your own instead of copying other peoples answer.

Comment: @saz Beg to differ. Iirc, my probability and stochastic calculus professors did not emphasise that difference between $[\limsup X_n \in B]$ and $\limsup [X_n \in B]$

Comment: @saz So my answer's right? :P

Comment: @BCLC It didn't say that, did I?

Comment: @saz so w/c part is wrong? :P