# If $X_n \stackrel{p, quickly}{\to} X$, then $X_n \to X$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

1. Without using hint, can I just do something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1538503/140308 ?
2. With using hint:

By continuity of probability, I think we have

$$P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} P(B_k)$$

where $B_k := \limsup_n A_{n,k}$

where $A_{n,k} := [|X_n - X| > \frac{1}{k}]$

By replacing, in our hypothesis, $\varepsilon$ with $\frac{1}{k}$ and by BCL1, I think we have

$$P(B_k) = 0$$

Hence

$$P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} P(B_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} 0 = 0$$

Is that right?

Comment: You can do even simpler. Once you know that $P(B_k)=0$ fo all $k$, you immediately have $P( \cup B_k ) \leq \sum P(B_k) = 0$ because of subadditivity.

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. Ah thanks XD post as answer? is mine right though?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. You can use continuity from below since the $B_k$ are increasing, though I'd consider it overkill. Also $P(B_k)=0$ does indeed follow from the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we deduce $P(B_k)$ from BCL1, we can say that by countable subadditivity we have

$$P(\bigcup_k B_k) \le \sum_k P(B_k) = \sum_k 0 = 0$$